# Passing Date/moment object via attribute in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have a `directive` and I'm trying to pass Date/moment object via `attribute`. I'm passing it like this: (I know, that I can create isolated-scope and bind it, it is not the case)

```
<form name="form">
  <input name="field" ng-model="fieldModel" form-field-directive field-date="{{fieldDateModel}}" />
</form>
```

Without curly brackets the result is obvious, but with I'm getting such quoted string `"2015-07-03T10:35:13.691Z"`.

Is there anyway to work with it?

**UPDATE:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.fieldDateModel = moment(); // new Date()
  });

angular.module('app')
  .directive('formFieldDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^ngModel',
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.fieldDate = function() {
          if (angular.isUndefined(iAttrs.fieldDate)) {
            return true;
          }

          console.log(iAttrs.fieldDate);
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Please show the directive code...

Comment: It is something like that, but I already solved it I think http://jsbin.com/pokaqa/1/edit?html,js,console,output.

Comment: Please update your question with the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually pull the value from the parent scope using `$parse` which is more reliable.

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('formFieldDirective', function($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^ngModel',
      link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.fieldDate = function() {
          if (angular.isUndefined(iAttrs.fieldDate)) {
            return true;
          }

          console.log(($parse(iAttrs.fieldDate)(scope)).format());
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/qoheraloge/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: What if it was passed statically? I found, that it is passed in ISO format and seems to me, that just checking it and handling accordingly is enough.

Comment: Statically `field-date="03.04.2017"` for example. i.e. http://jsbin.com/qequpo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Current question doesn't cover it. But I need to pass date via attribute to compare with `ngModel` assigned to the field. This way I don't need to create isolated-scope for directive.

Comment: You use the same strategy...`$parse`

Comment: If I pass date statically as attribute, not as a variable, then in your example I think I got error.

Comment: If you want the evaluated value of ngModel, use parse, if you want the plain attribute value, no need to use parse...